# How could unit test be used in integrated test/functional test to locate the bug?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit

when you write integrated test, it seems you cannot run unit test with real data that produced in  integrated tests.

for example, you have written a unit test:

```
class SomeClassTest{
    @Test
    somemothedTest (){
        push test data       //the data is build in 
        run target method of target class
    }
}
```

so, you have to refactor your unit test to accept test data from outside of this unit test case.

is it right?

in a junit book, the author wirte:

> .... Once you have the tests for a class up and running, the next step
>   is to hook up the class with other methods and services. ....

is this mean, we should refactor our unit test to make it can work togethor to form a large test and can be called by integrited test?

Comment: You have asked two quite different questions - one in the title, and one in the final sentence of the body.  The answer to the second question is "no".  The first question is really too broad to be answered on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @DavidWallace I mean, by run unit test together with integrited data, we can locate the bug, because the unit test will fall. If we cannot run unit test within integrited phase, How can we say that we can locate bug by using unit testing?

Comment: OK.  A unit test should always be self-contained.  It should never depend on data generated by some other test.  An integration test is a bit different; but frequently, integration tests find bugs too.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: @DavidWallace Yes! thank u. in junit in action, says: "Whereas a functional test tells you that a bug exists somewhere in the implementation of a use case, a unit test tells you that a specific
method is failing for a specific reason. You no longer need to spend hours trying to
find the problem." so, I suppose that the unit test will run also in integrited phase with integrited data.

Comment: No, that's kind of missing the point.  A unit test must be self-contained.  It can share data with other tests, sure; but it must not rely on other tests to run, either before it or after it.